# Xcode iPhone Programming check if a server is online

Tags: iphone, xcode, http

My app has to connect to a server, but sometimes when I test my application I don't have my server online, so the app remains stuck when opening.
How I can test programmatically if the server is online? Is there something like ping so i can verify the state of the server and then doing the normal work or not if it is offline? Thank you!

Comment: If your app remains stuck when opening because of this, your application startup time is at the whim of the network speed.  Perform network operations asynchronously, you won't regret it.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at Apple's [Reachability](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) example (you are encouraged to use it in your App Store-submitted apps).

Answer (score 0):

Use `[NSURLRequest + requestWithURL:cachePolicy:timeoutInterval:]` with a timeoutInterval.  Then your NSURLConnectionDelegate will get a callback if the request times out.